# ¿Cómo elimino el resultado del segundo input? Al ingresar y borrar el valor arroja un resultado como si fuese cero en vez del campo vacío

Tags: javascript, funciones

```
   <body>
    <main>
        <h2>Celcius to Fahrenheit</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="inputCelcius" placeholder="Input degrees Celcius here">
        <input type="text" class="input result" id="returnCelcius" disabled>
    </main>
    <script>
    const inputCelcius = document.getElementById('inputCelcius');
   
    inputCelcius.addEventListener('input', function CelciusToFahrenheit(celcius){
```

> Aquí me toma el valor "+ 32" que va a colocar después de borrar el input 'celcius'

```
        const fahrenheit = ((celcius.target.value * 1.8) + 32);
        const returner = document.getElementById('returnCelcius');
        returner.value = fahrenheit;
    })
```

> Precisamente quiero deshacerme de ese "32" que aparece tras borrar el input, que es el resultado de ingresar "0". No busco ingresar 0, quiero limpiar el campo cuando no hay ningún valor en la variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
const inputCelcius = document.getElementById('inputCelcius');
   
inputCelcius.addEventListener('input', function CelciusToFahrenheit(celcius){
    const fahrenheit = ((celcius.target.value * 1.8) + 32);
    const returner = document.getElementById('returnCelcius');
```

> Terminó funcionando con el siguiente condicional después de declarar las variables dentro de la función:

```
    if (inputCelcius.value.length == 0){ //O también: if (inputCelcius.value == ''){
        returner.value = null;
    }else{
        returner.value = fahrenheit;
    }
})
</script>
```